# How to intuitively understand the Boltzmann equations that come up in Cosmology?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, perturbation-theory, cosmic-microwave-background, structure-formation

This may be a silly question, but I have been reading through Dodelson's Modern Cosmology textbook and n Chapter 4 we derive the Boltzmann equation for different constituents of matter and radiation. In this, we are able to show

$\dot{\delta} = - ikv - 3 \dot{\Phi}$

where dots refer to derivatives with respect to conformal time, $\delta$ can be the matter or baryon overdensity, $k$ is the wavenumber of the mode in question, $v$ is the velocity of the cosmic fluid, and $\Phi$ is the perturbation to the spatial matrix such that

$ds^2 = -(1+2\Psi)dt^2 + a^2(1+2\Phi)\delta_{ij} dx^i dx^j $

where $t$ is the coordinate time, $\vec{x}$ is the position vector on the sky, and $a$ is the scale factor. And just for a reference, since the photon and neutrino quadrapole moment is very small when the universe was still a baryon-photon plasma we should expect $\Psi = - \Phi$.

Here is my confusion: Dodelson comments that an overdense region will have $\Phi>0$ and $\Psi<0$, so I would think that if gravity is causing matter to fall towards some point causing an overdensity to increase, $\dot{\delta}>0$, the gravitational potential would also increase such that $\dot{\Phi} >0$. However, from the equations it seems that if $\dot{\Phi}>0$ then $\dot{\delta}<0$ which is opposite to my intuition. Why does an overdensity grow when $\dot{\Phi}<0$ rather than $\dot{\Phi}>0$, and is this just a notation issue? It is a bit confusing as Dodelson remarks that an overdensity will have $\Phi>0$, so I would think an overdensity would increase when $\dot{\Phi}>0$.